# Is there a way to Route logs based on Marker with the RoutingAppender in Log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

It is possible to [filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter) messages using markers, such as :

```
      <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
```

However I'm trying to route a message based on the marker using the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender). I don't want to filter the same arguments multiple times in multiple Appenders. Here's my configuration sample (yaml):

```
Routing:
  name: ROUTING_APPENDER
  Routes:
    pattern: "$${ctx:marker}" #<-- How to use Marker here?
    Route:
      - key: MyRoutingKey
        ref: MyCustomAppender
```

The documentation stipulates :

> The pattern is evaluated against all the registered Lookups and the
>   result is used to select a Route

However there seems to be no [Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html) for Markers, same for LogLevel. It would be possible to add a custom *MarkerValue* or *LogLevelValue* in the [ThreadContextMap](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#ContextMapLookup) but I don't find the solution really efficient, it duplicates known information.

Is it not documented or just impossible?  Should there be a built-in way to have access to those values in Lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for RoutingAppender shows the ThreadContext lookup, but routing can also work with other lookups. One idea is to create a custom lookup.

A custom lookup is implemented as a log4j2 plugin. To help log4j2 find your plugin you can enable **packages="yourCustomPackage"** in your configuration file. Your plugin class needs to be on the classpath so log4j can find it. Here's the plugin code for the custom lookup:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

@Plugin(name = "marker", category = "Lookup")
public class MarkerLookup implements StrLookup {

    public String lookup(String key) {
        return null
    }

    public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key) {
        final Marker marker = event.getMarker();
        return marker == null ? null : marker.getName();
    }
}
```

And in the configuration file :

```
Routing:
  name: ROUTING_APPENDER
  Routes:
    pattern: "$${marker:}"
    Route:
    - key: PERFORMANCE
      ref: PERFORMANCE_APPENDER
    - key: PAYLOAD
      ref: PAYLOAD_APPENDER
    - key: FATAL
      ref: FATAL_APPENDER
    - ref: APPLICATION_APPENDER #Default route
```

Credits to the Log4j2 developers (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1015).

**UPDATE** : According to them, it should be built-in in the next version (2.4). So no needs to write custom plugin after that.