# How to add slf4j marker in quarkus application logs

Tags: java, slf4j, marker, quarkus

Using quarkus version 1.5.2.Final

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("test").info(MarkerFactory.getMarker("TEST_MARKER"),"log statement");
```

This gets logged as :

> 2020-09-12 21:08:08,282 INFO  [test] (executor-thread-1) log statement

I would also like to include TEST_MARKER in this logline.
Unfortunately Quarkus logging guide doesn't even talk about markers.
My application.properties looks like this

```
    quarkus.http.port=8181
quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true
quarkus.resteasy.gzip.enabled=true
quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json
microprofile.rest.client.disable.default.mapper=true
```

Comment: You can probably do something based on the underlying logging framework you are using.  Like in Log4j, you could add your own custom appender.  This SO post talks about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247698/how-to-modify-a-log4j2-message-before-it-is-logged